# error with webpack when follow official tutorial

Tags: javascript, webpack

When I learn webpack I follow this tutorial: http://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/
I run `webpack ./entry.js bundle.js` after I installed webpack(use the same command as the tutorial) and create just the exact files as the tutorail. Then I got the error.

```
 "module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'assert/'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.require.resolve (module.js:388:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-libs-browser/index.js:1:93)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/lib/node/NodeSourcePlugin.js:7:23)
"
```

The enviroment is osx 10.10.3 and node is v0.12.4.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure Webpack is installed correctly in your system?

Regardless of that it's preferable to use a local install. Here are some quick instructions so you can give it a go. Follow at your project directory:

1. `npm init`
2. Just hit return for everything unless you feel like tweaking some. This will generate `package.json` at your project root
3. Hit `npm i webpack --save-dev`. This will attach Webpack as a development dependency to your project.
4. Hit `node_modules/.bin/webpack ./entry.js bundle.js`

Alternatively you can set up a `scripts` section like this at your `package.json`:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack ./entry.js bundle.js"
    }
}
```

If you hit `npm run build` after this, it will perform the same thing.

I go into a lot more detail at my [freely available book about Webpack](http://survivejs.com/webpack_react/). You can find more advanced ways to deal with it there.

Comment: Thank you.It really works.I still can't get why I could not use the global webpack( it is really installed globally because I hit "webpack" and I got the version info and options list.

Comment: Can you check what version your globally installed Webpack has? In any case it's a very good idea to go with a local Webpack as that will work with CI and help you to avoid version related issues over longer term (version controlled per project).

Comment: The version is webpack 1.9.10

Comment: It's hard to say. I cannot see anything obvious. You could try to report this issue at [node-libs-browser](https://github.com/webpack/node-libs-browser) given the global install seems to crash there or alternatively try [webpack issue tracker](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues).